# How to make latest ember.js efficient and upgrading from 1.4 to latest?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using Ember.js and I think the programming part is kind of cool, but the filesize on the library kind of feels horrific.

[image]

I had a simple list-details view application created in 1.4 ember and now picked up the latest ember.js for upgrading my project. Now I supposedly need this ember-template-compiler also. Any upgrading tips and advice on file size?

I settled for the 1.8 version instead, which seemed kind of compatible with my version. But still a upgrading advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think first of all you should port your application to Ember CLI, so you won't need `ember-template-compiler` in your production application. If you've read a [note about compiling templates on server side vs client side](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html#toc_server-side-compilation) there's an information:

> If possible, it is definitely a best practice to compile your
>   templates server side. This is much faster due to less total size (you
>   don't need the compiler on the client) and less work that the app
>   needs to do.

Also your code is minified, jQuery etc. goes to one big file `vendor.js` and you should probably focus on porting app to Ember CLI which will solve problem at least with `ember-template-compiler` file.

Comment: Aha, I wasn't aware of the changes.